# Justification for using "naive" probability (counting elements in space) on a SUB-task/step of overall experiment?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider a question like :

There is an urn, with $6$ white balls, and $8$ green balls. We will choose $2$ balls successively. In first selection, whatever color ball we choose, we have to replace it back into urn WITH an additional $2$ balls of that color.

What is the probability that for this experiment you pick a green ball on second selection?

---

My struggles:

Even though I know how to solve these kind of problems (condition on first choice, and using counting techniques), I cannot tie it to basic probability rules. The mathematics is fairly easy, but...

I do not understand exactly why we can use naive probability (counting techniques) on the two selections separately (further, on 2nd selection we use naive probability on a conditional probability - which adds another wrinkle).

I do these problems without wondering too much about this, but it bothers me.

Can someone provide a theorem or justification for allowing the use of naive probabilities in such questions from first principles? (laws of probability, sample spaces, etc.)

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by naive probability? In finite cases, the counting measure is perfectly justified from a measure theoretic point of view.

Comment: Naive probability meaning we can simply using counting arguments to count favourable outcomes vs. total outcomes.  How are we justified in using this to solve most problems where there is a complex sample space (e.g., the problem I posted has 2 steps in overall experiments) which is really based on the results of multiple sub-steps/sub-experiments?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the outcomes *in each stage* can be *justified* as being *equi-probable*, you may use the "naive" approach of measuring the conditional probability of that stage as an *outcome count ratio* of the favoured event versus the sample space.   Exactly as you could for a more direct senario; for the same reason.

So the probability of the first selection being a green ball is: $\mathsf P(S_1=g)=\frac{8}{6+8}$, because there are 6 white balls and 8 green balls in the urn and there is *no bias* in selecting any particular ball.

Likewise, the conditional probability of the second selection being green, when given that the first selection will be green, is: $\mathsf P(S_2=g\mid S_1=g)=\frac{8+2}{6+8+2}$ because two extra green balls had been added to the urn (along with the returned first selection) and there is *no bias* –at that point– in then selecting any particular ball now in the urn.

And so forth for the other parts of the sample space.   Then by the Law of Total Probability:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(S_2=g)~=&~\mathsf P(S_1=g)\,\mathsf P(S_2=g\mid S_1=g)+\mathsf P(S_1=w)\,\mathsf P(S_2=g\mid S_1=w)\\[1ex]=&~ \frac{8}{6+8}{\cdot}\frac{8+2}{6+8+2}+\frac{6}{6+8}{\cdot}\frac{8}{6+8+2}\\[1ex]=&~ \frac{4}{7}\end{align}$$

That is all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use the concept of *expected value*,
the computations in such problems becomes much simpler.

Obviously, there will be a total of $16$ balls at the end,

and the expected number of green balls will be $8 + 2\cdot\frac8{14}= \frac{64}7$

Thus $Pr = \frac{64/7}{16} = \frac47$

Answer (score 0):

As always, mathematics studies abstract models, and people choose how to apply them to concrete situations. The same happens in physics: are we justified in using $\mathbb{R}^3$ as the model for our space? Nobody could prove this, it is not a mathematical question. But it does seem reasonable, and it works well.

And in any case, the naive approach of counting is a sound model and it is perfectly applicable, as long as we are convinced that all the events that we are counting have the same likelihood to happen.

Now, to the point: at the first extraction, we have a $8/14$ probability to pick a green ball, which just means that over $14$ possible cases there are $8$ where the ball is green. Since the problem is more complex, with two extractions, the number of cases is actually larger, but if you want we can still do the computation from the basics, without any formula, and considering all balls to be different (so that they are all equiprobable to come out). If you compute this, you have $6\times8=48$ cases in which you take out twice a white ball, $48$ for white and then green, $80$ for twice green, and finally $48$ for green and then white. This means that you have $128$ favorable cases over a total of $224$, which gives a probability of $\frac{128}{224}=\frac{4}{7}$.

Of course, it would be impractical to count always every single case, so that you simply define events like "green after white" and compute their probabilities with the well-known formulas. But at the bottom, if you think about it, it is really quite the same thing.

I hope this helps ;)